# js функция закрытия popup (крестик)

Tags: javascript

```
Написал функцию закрытия попапов на крестик чтоб не вешать на каждый крестик переменную 
но функция работает со 2 ого запуска тобишь закрываешь попап например на Escape и только со 2 ого открытия срабатывает + в консоль при нажатии на крестик (закрытия) выводится элемент кнопка открытия попапа хотя по факту ты жмешь на закрытие 

html
<--!--модальное окно(профиль)-->
    <section class="popup popup_type_profile">
      <div class="popup__container">
        <button type="button" class="popup__exit"></button>
        <form
          action="index.html"
          method="post"
          name="profile"
          id="formprofile"
          novalidate
        >
          <fieldset class="popup__contact">
            <h2 class="popup__heading">Редактировать профиль</h2>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="popup__line"
              id="researcher"
              name="researcher"
              placeholder="Имя"
              required
              minlength="2"
              maxlength="40"
            />
            <span class="popup__line-error popup__line_type_researcher"></span>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="popup__line"
              id="eco"
              name="eco"
              placeholder="Профессиональная деятельность"
              required
              minlength="2"
              maxlength="200"
            />
            <span class="popup__line-error popup__line_type_eco"></span>
            <button type="submit" class="popup__save-button">Сохранить</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- модальное окно (добавление карточек)-->
    <section class="popup popup_type_card">
      <div class="popup__container">
        <button type="button" class="popup__exit"></button>
        <form
          action="index.html"
          method="post"
          name="formcard"
          id="formcard"
          novalidate
        >
          <fieldset class="popup__contact">
            <h2 class="popup__heading">Новое место</h2>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="popup__line"
              id="namecard"
              name="namecard"
              placeholder="Название"
              required
              minlength="2"
              maxlength="30"
            />
            <span class="popup__line-error popup__line_type_namecard"></span>
            <input
              type="url"
              class="popup__line"
              id="linkcard"
              name="linkcard"
              placeholder="Ссылка на картинку"
              required
              pattern="https?://.+"
            />
            <span class="popup__line-error popup__line_type_linkcard"></span>
            <button type="submit" class="popup__save-button">Создать</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

js 

const clickExit = (evt) => {
  const exit = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".popup__exit"));
  exit.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
      evt.target.closest(".popup");
      console.log(evt.target);
      closePopup(evt.target);
    });
  });
};
document.addEventListener("click", clickExit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
нужно было разделить на 2 функции ...ошибка была в 2 ом обработчике 

const clickExit = (evt) => {
  closePopup(evt.target.closest(".popup"));
};
const exit = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".popup__exit")).forEach(
  (element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", clickExit);
  }
);
```